# How to set Android USB configuration programatically?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am making an Android App and I need a different USB configuration for this. I know I can go into Developer Options->Select USB Configuration. However, I would like to do this programatically so that I can change the USB configuration in the app. For instance, I would like to set it to MTP when my app is open. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I tried looking it up but couldn't find much. Since the option for it is in develop options I'm inferring I can do this in my program somehow.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not under developer control, except perhaps on rooted devices.

Comment: Take a look at the source code for the OS you are working on. Might be a method to select the mode.

Comment: Also take at looking the settings database directly.